# Fails to position elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am still learning CSS. I am creating a game with time and score.

To be short I want to create this:

[image: What I want to achive]

And this is what I have:

[image: What I have now]

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/yZKTE/

CSS:

```
#boxbuttons {
    /*text-align: center;*/
/*  margin: 20px;*/
    display: block;
        top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding:50px;
    /*width:900px;*/
}
#boxbuttons .button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#rezz
{ 
   background:url(../images/score.png) left top; 
   width:35px;
   height:35px;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#counter{
    margin-left:50px;
}
#time
{ 
   background:url(../images/time.png) right top; 
   width:35px;
   height:35px;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#ttime{
    margin-right:50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <span id="boxbuttons">
    <span class="button" id="rezz">
      <span id="counter">0</span>
    </span>
      <span class="button" id="time"><span class="button" id="ttime"></span></span>
  </span>
```

Comment: To position an element, it needs to have some other position than `static`, in other words, you have to add a position

Comment: You might find [CSS float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) helpful.

Comment: You can position elements with `position: static`, and without floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `#time` css like so:

```
#time
{ 
   background:url("http://remake.hr/memtest/images/time.png") right top; 
   width:100px;
   height:35px;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   display: inline-block;
   float:right;
}
```

The `span` HTML element is by default `display:inline`, meaning that width and height attributes do not affect it. By setting it to `display:inline-block`, this allows the width attribute to take charge. I changed the width to `100px` because otherwise it was too small. I also added the `float:right` attribute because that tells the element to float to the rightmost position inside its parent element.

http://jsfiddle.net/yZKTE/1/

EDIT:

Do this to move the time to the right side of the clock icon:

```
#time {
  background: url("http://remake.hr/memtest/images/time.png") left top;
  width: 145px;
  height: 35px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding:0!important;
}

#ttime {
  float: right;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yZKTE/4/

Comment: It's great but is there any way to place minutes and seconds next to image from right side like on image on original post?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of this that are causing this problem.

The first thing you're going to want to do is "shrink wrap" your outer `div`. This will make it so that when you `float` an element, it will `float` to the right of the parent `div`, not the outermost `div`. This is hard to explain, but put the following CSS in, and notice the width of the `#picbox` div shrink to be as wide as it's contents.

```
#picbox {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Your `#boxcard` CSS has `margin: 0 auto;` which is centering it. You want to remove this, which will start the `#boxcard` div all the way to the left. Add some `margin-left` to the div to get it to line up with the header. Like this:

```
#boxcard {
    -webkit-perspective:1000;
       -moz-perspective:1000;
        -ms-perspective:1000;
         -o-perspective:1000;
            perspective:1000;
    display: table;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Lastly, lets get your `#time` div to float to the right. First, change `#time` to `#boxbuttons #time` so that it overrides your `#boxbuttons .button` styles. First, we're going to `float` it right with `float: right;`. Then, we're going to remove the `width` you've set, so that it takes up `auto` width. Lastly, we'll give it some `padding-left` and change the `background` to `left top`, so that the time and the clock image are separated from each other, and the clock is now on the left.

```
#boxbuttons #time { 
   background:url("http://remake.hr/memtest/images/time.png") left top; 
   height:35px;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   float: right;
   padding-left: 30px;
}
```

I think that's everything.

http://jsfiddle.net/yZKTE/6/

Comment: I see no real difference between http://jsfiddle.net/yZKTE/ and http://jsfiddle.net/yZKTE/2/

Comment: That's because your screen width is too small. He has the `#boxcard` div centered, which is dragging it away from the header.

Comment: Edited above to have everything. You're also going to want to increase the `font-size`s of your `#counter` and `#time` elements, so that they match the image in your post.

Comment: Nice code I must say. But problem is that "counter"  (minutes and seconds) are on wrong position. They need to be placed next to clock image from right side. Can it be done with your code @MattDiamant ?

Comment: Yes, changed the `#boxbuttons #time` CSS to fix it.